# Zip Icon changed to a blue 'A' associated with fontview.exe

Tags: windows-7, zip

I made the mistake of associating `fontview.exe` in the right click "Open With" window, trying to install a font from a zip folder in Windows 7.

Now all my zip folders now have a blue "A" on them and they will not open when I click on them. I'm forced to use "open with" and select WinZip or 7-Zip which will extract. Windows Explorer will not open the files at all.

I tried setting a new file association under "Default Programs"/"Associate" a File Type but it didn't accept either unzip program. It remains with the current program – Windows Font Viewer.

I checked the registry for the "open with" defaults for zip and it was correct but the icon remains a blue A with `fontview.exe` as associated program.

How can I fix the association?

Answer (score 0):

When you choose "Open with" instead of choosing the program you want to open it with, select "Choose Default Program". Then, just choose the program you want to always use to open zips, and make sure that the checkbox at the bottom is selected to change to default.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type or paste `regedit.exe` in the text box, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. Navigate to the following key:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.zip
   ```
3. Right-click the `UserChoice` subkey, and choose **Delete** from the context menu.
4. Log off and log back on.

Answer (score 0):

**Found the solution here**-- http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/155/
asked google a different way-- 'change current default of zip program windows 7' and found the above suggestions. Used the second method- registry change and it worked!